# How to create a pause button in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I've been trying to make a game, and everything in there works so far except that the pause button , that when pressed the button P should pause and when pressed S should continue. I kinda understand the problem such that once in enters the while loop in the main code it wont get out. I tried putting the pause function inside the while loop. Please do help or provide tips to fix if possible thank you.

```
import pygame

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
Blue = (2,55,55)



def recursive_draw(x, y, width, height):
    """ Recursive rectangle function. """
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,
                     [x, y, width, height],
                     1)
    speed = [10,0]
    rect_change_x = 10
    rect_change_y = 10




    # Is the rectangle wide enough to draw again?
    if (width > 25):
        # Scale down
        x += width * .1
        y += height * .1
        width *= .8
        height *= .8


               # Recursively draw again
        recursive_draw(x, y, width, height)

def recursive_draw2(x, y, width, height):
    """ Recursive rectangle function. """
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Blue,
                     [x, y, width, height],
                     1)
    speed = [10,0]
    rect_change_x = 10
    rect_change_y = 10




    # Is the rectangle wide enough to draw again?
    if (width > 25):
        x += width * .1
        y += height * .1
        width *= .8
        height *= .8



               # Recursively draw again
        recursive_draw2(x, y, width, height)
def paused():
    screen.fill(black)

    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        #gameDisplay.fill(white)


        button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)  


pygame.init()
#rectanglelist = [big()] 
# Set the height and width of the screen
size = [700, 500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
black=(0,0,0)

end_it=False
time = 100

USEREVENT = 0

pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1, 10)
milliseconds = 0
seconds = 0
start_it = False
while (end_it==False):
    screen.fill(black)
    myfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
    nlabel=myfont.render("Welcome to "+ " Jet shooter ", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    label=myfont.render("Click on the mouse to start ", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            end_it=True

    screen.blit(nlabel,(200, 100))
    screen.blit(label, (170,300))
    pygame.display.flip()

while (start_it==False):

    screen.fill(black)
    myfont2=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
    label2=myfont2.render("Ready?", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label2, (300,250))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(3000)
    start_it = True
fall = False   
while (fall==False):
    nlist = [3,2,1]
    for i in (nlist):


        screen.fill(black)
        n = str(i)
        myfont3=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
        score = myfont3.render(n,1,(255,0,0))
        screen.blit((score), (350,250))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(1000)
    screen.fill(black)
    myfont4=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
    label4=myfont3.render("GOOO!!!", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label4, (300,250))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait (1000)

    fall = True
pause = 0             
b = 0

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

             if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                 if event.key==K_p:
                     pause=True
                 if pause == True:
                     screen.fill(black)
                     font=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
                     nlabelBB=myfont.render("Pause", 1, (255, 0, 0))
                     screen.blit(nlabelBB,(200, 100))
                     pygame.display.flip()



        # Set the screen background
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        flip = 1
        a = 0

    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT


        recursive_draw(0, 0, 700, 500)


        recursive_draw2(35,25, 625, 450)
**###I TRIED TO PUT THE PAUSE GAME HERE AND IF PRESSED P PAUSE AND S CONTINUE
        while  a == 0 :


            if flip == 1 :
                recursive_draw(35,25,625,450)
                recursive_draw2(0, 0, 700, 500)

                flip = flip + 1
                pygame.display.flip()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                     if event.key==K_p:
                         a = 1
                         screen.fill(black)
                         font=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
                         nlabelBB=myfont.render("Pause", 1, (255, 0, 0))
                         screen.blit(nlabelBB,(200, 100))
                         pygame.display.flip()
                     if event.key==K_s:
                         a = 0





            if flip == 2 :
                recursive_draw(0, 0, 700, 500)
                recursive_draw2(35, 25, 625, 450)

                flip = flip - 1
                pygame.display.flip()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                     if event.key==K_p:
                         a = 1
                         screen.fill(black)
                         font=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
                         nlabelBB=myfont.render("Pause", 1, (255, 0, 0))
                         screen.blit(nlabelBB,(200, 100))
                         pygame.display.flip()
                     if event.key==K_s:
                         a = 0**

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True





    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 60 frames per second
clock.tick(20)

# Be IDLE friendly. If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit.
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This link might help... https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/334979/adding-pause-feature-in-pygame

Answer (score 4):

Just use a single game loop for everything and keep track of the current *state* (e.g. main menu, pause screen, game scene) of your game..

Here's an example where we keep track of the *state* by a simple variable called `state` and act in our game loop accordingly:

```
import pygame, math, itertools

def magnitude(v): 
    return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))

def sub(u, v):
    return [u[i]-v[i] for i in range(len(u))]

def normalize(v): 
    return [v[i]/magnitude(v)  for i in range(len(v))]

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()    

path = itertools.cycle([(26, 43), (105, 110), (45, 225), (145, 295), (266, 211), (178, 134), (250, 56), (147, 12)])
target = next(path)
ball, speed = pygame.rect.Rect(target[0], target[1], 10, 10), 3.6
pause_text = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 32).render('Pause', True, pygame.color.Color('White'))

RUNNING, PAUSE = 0, 1
state = RUNNING

while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT: break
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == pygame.K_p: state = PAUSE
            if e.key == pygame.K_s: state = RUNNING
    else:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        if state == RUNNING:
            target_vector = sub(target, ball.center) 

            if magnitude(target_vector) < 2: 
                target = next(path)
            else:
                ball.move_ip([c * speed for c in normalize(target_vector)])

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.color.Color('Yellow'), ball)

        elif state == PAUSE:
            screen.blit(pause_text, (100, 100))

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        continue
    break
```

As you can see, the rectangle keeps moving until you press <kbd>P</kbd>, which will change the state to `PAUSE`; and a simple message will now be displayed instead of drawing/moving the rectangle further.

If you press <kbd>S</kbd> the state switches back to the normal mode; all done in a single game loop.

Further reading:

- [Pygame level/menu states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727074/142637)
- [Mulitple Displays in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107111/142637)
- [Trying to figure out how to track Pygame events and organize the game's functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18693749/142637)